# Offset an anchor section for a fixed header

Tags: html, css

I've seen other answers, but none of them seem to work for me.

What I want: when I type the URL `.../page.html#two` to go to `#two`, but with a 50px offset from the top of the page.

**note: ive added the `big space` and `<a>'s` because you can't type the url in jsfiddle. I want it to work with urls, as well as with links.**

```
<body>
    <section id="one">First section</section>
    <section id="two">Second section</section>
    <section id="three">Third section</section>
    <div id="big_space"></div>
    <a href="#one">one</a>
    <a href="#two">two</a>
    <a href="#three">three</a>
</body>

body
{
    height: 2000px;
}

#big_space
{
    height: 1000px;
}

section
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here's a link to the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAmCL/

I have tried using the `section:before` but it seems to give the wrong result (i've commented it out in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to do with pure CSS as you want it, though there are some semi-work arounds

This approach only works in certain instances, but the trick is to use `margin-top:-50px; padding-top:50px;`. This makes the element appear in the same position except for the background will be `50px` higher and pushed up `50px`. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NBqkF/1/) of that approach

The second approach which I'd recommend more is one involving an added inner element. I decided to format each one like so `<section id="one"><div class="reference" id="refOne"></div>First section</section>`. Then you can point to the refence in the link, i.e. `<a href="#oneRef">one</a>`. Then all it takes it the following simple CSS

```
section {
    ... Your other lines ...
    position:relative;
}
.reference {
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NBqkF/2/). This approach leaves all of the elements the way they were before in performance and looks but requires slight additional HTML markup

It'd be nice to be able to reference element's pseuo-elements like you tried to do but I understand how it could be non-syntactically correct to do so

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying for hours trying to get this to work in a way that plays nicely, however every change seems to cause more grief. eg, adding a border caused the pseudo-element to collapse. I ended up doing something similar to your second approach.